# mysql: replicated data or LIKE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table on my database where i store some informations about some files on my server like "timestamp, owner, keywords".

Now i need to search element inside this table by using only timestamp, or only owner, or only a keyword, or any combination of that fields.

Now, keywords contains multiple keywords (but for searching only one is admitted) and my research should be as fast as possible (table will contains a lot of entries).

Now it's more efficient to use LIKE clause as

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE keywords LIKE '%to_search%'
```

or create a table for each keywords and store data (timestamp and owner) inside it, and have heavy data redundancy?

Comment: it is almost never more efficient to have LIKE %something% because indexes cannot be used with a wildcard at both ends. if you are able to "nomalize" your design, and index the keywords, this is likely to be faster - but we don't have a lot of detail.

Comment: keywords field contain a variable number of default keyword assigned from user when a new file is created

Comment: ca u use => SELECT * FROM table WHERE keywords LIKE '%to_search% '  . One blank space at the end to see end of the word,seaparate word

Comment: like clause is much more efficient than duplicate data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normalized database design, you would have a table each for files, keywords, and the relationship between files and keywords.

So, the KEYWORDS table would look like (primary key: keyword_id)

```
keyword_id  keyword_desc
1           test
2           mysql
3           query
4           database
```

... the FILES table would look like (primary key: file_id)

```
file_id timestamp    owner
1       2013-04-12   John
2       2013-01-01   Joseph
```

...and the FILES_KEYWORDS table would look like (primary key: file_id, keyword_id)

```
file_id  keyword_id
1        1
1        3
2        2
```

You can then query the files containing keywords, as below:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM files f
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT fk.file_id file_id
FROM files_keywords fk
INNER JOIN keywords k
ON fk.keyword_id = k.keyword_id AND k.keyword_desc = <search keyword>
) files_with_keywords
ON f.file_id = files_with_keywords.file_id;
```

Replace `<search keyword>` with the keyword for which you are performing the search.

This way, the indexes would be used as expected, rendering optimal performance.